# Cannot resolve parameter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer.IApiDescriptionGroupCollectionProvider apiDescriptionsProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, swagger

We use swagger for explore api and one time we turned off razor.

And this led to problem with swagger

Original error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
DependencyResolutionException: None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' 
  on type 'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
Cannot resolve parameter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer.IApiDescriptionGroupCollectionProvider apiDescriptionsProvider' 
  of constructor 'Void .ctor(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer.IApiDescriptionGroupCollectionProvider, Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.ISchemaRegistryFactory, Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions`1[Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGeneratorOptions])'.
Cannot resolve parameter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer.IApiDescriptionGroupCollectionProvider apiDescriptionsProvider' 
of constructor 'Void .ctor(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer.IApiDescriptionGroupCollectionProvider, Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.ISchemaRegistryFactory, Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGeneratorOptions)'.
Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.GetValidConstructorBindings(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable<Parameter> parameters)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How the problem appeared: we used `services.AddMvcCore` instead `services.AddMvc`

How resolve: add registration of `ApiExplorer`

For example:

```cs
services.AddMvcCore()
    .AddJsonFormatters()
    .AddApiExplorer(); // this line is solution of problem
```

Comment: same issue I had.
for swashbuckle, dotnet 5 

https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#swashbuckle-apiexplorer-and-routing

Comment: Worked for updating from .NET Core 2.2 to .NET Core 3.1

Answer (score 2):

I used `AddMvc()` and it got resolved

For example:

```
services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);
```